# js: how to intercept the suffix of domain name

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to intercept the suffix in the domain name`.` How can I intercept the content between the last letter and the first `/`

```js
let str1 = 'https://mail.xxx.net/main/';
// net

let str2 = 'https://blog.xxx.me/';
// me

let str3 = 'https://xxx.blog.com/home';
// com

let str4 = 'https://xxx.blog/home/#container';
// blog



console.log(`${str1}\n${str2}\n${str3}\n${str4}\n`)
```

Comment: What use is the "suffix"? That's just some random junk these days. Look at a [domain parser](https://github.com/lupomontero/psl). If you can't include that dependency, you can at least snip the code you need.

Comment: @tadman That...  I just want to collect some common websites, i need to give the layout a style

Comment: I have no idea what you just said. Are you looking for a list of gTLDs?

Comment: @tadman I'm really sorry, my English is not very good. What I want to express is that I want to make a personal website collection page. I want to use the suffix of the website instead of the image of the website to complete a layout.

Comment: An odd thing to do considering gTLDs are these days pretty much random and meaningless, especially for countries like Italy that has a "cool" TLD, but sure.

Comment: What about top level domains (TLDs) such as `.co.ke`, `.gov.uk`, `.org.za` and similar ones, composed by a gTLD *and* a ccTLD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a simple regex:

```js
const url = 'https://xxx.blog/home/#container';

const domain = url.match(/^https?:\/\/.+\.([^\/]+)\/.*/);

console.log(domain[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it should be a blog, not a blog xxx.blog

Comment: Ok, I edited it so that it only captures the last part :)

Answer (score 2):

A solution without regex:

```js
let str1 = 'https://mail.xxx.net/main/';
// net

let str2 = 'https://blog.xxx.me/';
// me

let str3 = 'https://xxx.blog.com/home';
// com

let str4 = 'https://xxx.blog/home/#container';
// blog


const getSuffix = (str) => {
  const aux = str.split('//')[1].split('/')[0];
  return aux.substring(aux.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
}

console.log(getSuffix(str1),getSuffix(str2),getSuffix(str3),getSuffix(str4))
```